# Android Asynk Task run in thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i want to run asynk task in every 5 seconds till 5 minuts, how can i do this ?
i am able to run asynk task in every 5 seconds but can no limit 5 minuts

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new CheckTxnStatusSTResult().execute(final_verification_card);
                        Log.d("dinesh","execute in every five seconds"+ final_verification_card);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 15000);

}
```

Comment: That task will run every 15 seconds just btw

Comment: oh sorry ! but i need to run this till 5 minute

Comment: Why are you using handler.post if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you can do like this

```
public void FunctionName() {
    new CountDownTimer(Total_time, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            MyUtils.Log("execute in every one seconds");
            // Display Data by Every Ten Second
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
           // Call Other function on Function
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: cant get desire result

Comment: sorry guys ! this code run asynktask till to infinte . never stops